# Replace browser url without redirect, using javascript when ajax call return response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am finding the solution to replace the url without reloading the page. I am using infinite scroll javascript plugin.When ajax call return the result I want to replace the url with new post url.

For example.
Current url: http://example.com/category/

Response by ajax call: http://example.com/post-testing/.
I want to replace the `category` with `the post-testing` without reloading.

I used `document.location.hash` and `window.history.pushState('', '', url);` functions but these did not meet the requirements.

Comment: I might be pessimistic but I don't think you can change the URL without reloading the page (you can with `#hash` but it's not what you're looking for).

Answer (score 1):

As it so happens it works with `history.pushState(obj,title,url)`. So in your case

```
history.pushState('','','my_awesome_arl_from_ajax_response');
```

Does not work on jsfiddle inside their environment, but works otherwise.